# Store value history in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time-series

Let's say we need to store reading of temperature sensors and keep a history, for every day. Each measure is a tuple `day: number, value: string` (some days could be missed that's why we need to store the day explicitly). There are hundreds of thousands of sensors.

Adding new measurement should not require re-reading and re-write the whole object, it should be **small incremental addition**.

And, there could be multiple reading for the same day. In such case, if day is the same **only the latest measurement for that day should be kept**.

What data structure should be used? I can see the following ways:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_history (
  sensor_id integer,
  time      integer[],
  value     text[]
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_history (
  sensor_id integer,
  history   json/jsonb/hstore
);
```

Comment: Regardless of the design, you are going to be storing a lot of information.  Have you looked into using NoSQL?

Comment: Yes, I see your point about NoSQL but for some other reasons in this case PostgreSQL would be better choice.

Comment: It depends on what you plan to do with the data.  If you don't need a log of RDBMS functionality, then a NoSQL data store becomes more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store one row per tuple? e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_history (
  sensor_id integer,
  time      integer,
  value     text
);
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But would it be efficient? If we have 1million sensors, after 1 month there will be 30mln in history, and after 1 year 360mln.

Comment: Efficient in what way? I have worked with databases having billions of rows in a table without problems. As long as you are not trying to run queries that will do full table scans, there is not much of an issue. Putting an index on `sensor_id` will prevent full scans for loading data from a specific sensor, for example.